Want to mock MongoDB.Driver in appropriate manner to store data in memory considering FilterDefinition and UpdateDefinition
I am writing integration test and want to mock MongoDB.Driver in appropriate manner to store data in memory considering FilterDefinition and UpdateDefinition so all the operations can be performed with in C# object using probably Lambda.
I appreciate any help on this.
I already tried to convert it to BsonDocument and build predicate accordingly but FilterDefinition is very complex and its hard to handle each aspect by using predicate manually.
var documentSerializer = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<TDocument>();
var renderedFilter = filters.Render(documentSerializer, BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry); 

I also tried Mongo2Go but integration time is increasing by introducing this.

Have you considered hosting a memory mongodb for your tests?

I don't recommend it, you should not test code that doesn't belong to you. Make test/mocking for the code that call mongo db driver (repository or similar)

Thanks @GoodNightNerdPride for your response, Is this a tool similar to Mongo2Go?

Thanks @dododo for your response, I am not testing their code. Since I am mocking Mongo collection at my end as part of my integration tests, I need to apply filtering and update but UpdateDefinition and FilterDefinition are the area where I got blocked as I need to apply all the operations on  C# dictionary.

Yes it is. Mongo2go seems like the better choice though. Implementing too much logic in a mock is a codesmell in my opinion.

@VedSinghal, still what you're describing sounds weird/wrong. I got blocked as I need to apply all the operations on C# dictionary.  - if so why you need mongo driver? I'm 99% confident there is a better design for what you need, but you didn't provide enough details yet  to suggest something
